# Exception handling in Django/DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to check for correctness of request.data whenever there would be a POST request to `127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/events/`
Currently, I do have Event model

```
class Event(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250) 
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_events', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    event_type = models.CharField(choices=EventType.choices, max_length=10) 
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Whenever there would be a PATCH request `127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/events/{pk}`. Then, `updated_time`, `event_type` should not be in the request.data (meaning that they should not be updated). How can I make sure that everything is correct in the request.data?

It can be done by checking

```
request_keys = request.data.keys() 
actual_keys = self.serializer_class().get_fields().keys() 
result = [x for x in request_keys if x not in actual_keys] 
if result: 
    return Response({'error': 'Invalid data'}, status=400)
```

But the problem is that, I do need to check for different fields whenever the request.method is different, like, POST and PATCH, `.get_fields()` will return just all the fields in serializer. However, for PATCH I should not have `updated_time`, `event_type` fields.

This is my EventView code

```
def create(self, request): 
    serializer = EventSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    error_response = self._validate_request_data(request.data) 
    if error_response is not None: 
        return error_response 
    user, event_id = request.user, request.data['event'] 
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id) 
    ... 
    ... 

def partial_update(self, request):
    error_response = self._validate_request_data(request.data)
    if error_response is not None:
        return error_response
    ...
    ...
   
def _validate_request_data(self, request_data): 
    request_keys = request_data.keys() 
    actual_keys = self.serializer_class().get_fields().keys() 
    result = [x for x in request_keys if x not in actual_keys] 
    if result: 
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid data'}, status=400)
    ...
    ...
```

But do not know how to separate those `.get_fields()` for different HTTP_METHODS.

Answer (score 0):

Django restframework Serializers have the read-only fields if you use the ModelSerializer like below.

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Event 
        fields = '__all__' 
        read_only_fields = ['created_by', 'created_time', 'updated_time']
```

Another thing you can do is also you can use validate method inside your serializers either for all fields or only one specific on.

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Event 
        fields = '__all__' 
        read_only_fields = ['created_by', 'created_time', 'updated_time']
        
    # Drop event_type from the response
    def validate_event_type(self, value): 
        return None

    # or 
    def validate(self, data): 
        data.pop('event_type') 
        return data
```

To only restrict some fields in a specific request you can edit the above `validate` method like below.

```
def validate(self, data):
    # only in PATCH requests
    request = self.context.get('request')
    if request.method == 'PATCH':
        data.pop('event_type') 
    return data
```

Don't mess up with your view most of the time you can do stuff from the validator.

I believe you can refer to the documentation it is really a great place to refer they have a good documentation.

Also check the ViewSet in the restframework docs.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

According to the djangorestframework [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields)

> Model fields which have editable=False set, and AutoField fields will be set to read-only by default, and do not need to be added to the read_only_fields option.

So these fields will not be affected while performing `serializer.save()` irrespective of any `request.method` used. To update these fields, we have to get the object instance and update them explicitly like:

```py
event_obj.some_read_only_field = some_value
event_obj.save()
```

Even if the request data contains the value, those fields will not get updatated.

Now the question is how we set the fields like `event_type` as in your model while creating an object i.e. for "POST" request. For this type of field, setting `editable=False` would be not resonable as it should be able to use value from `request.data` during create `POST` request.

To avoid the update for `event_type` field we can implement following things:

- Implement a separate seraializer for the UPDATE request with `event_type` as `read_only` field.
- Popping the `event_type` key from the request data before feeding it to the serializer
- Modify the `serializer.update` method to avoid the update value for `event_data`
- Modify the `save` method in the model itself to avoid the update for `event_type` field.

For me personally, writing two different serializers is more cleaner:

```
class EventCreateSerializer():
  class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = "__all__"

class EventUpdateSerializer():
  class Meta:
    model = Event
    exclude = ["event_type"]
```

Using this in APIView is fairly easy. We can provide separate serializers based on action in viewsets too like:

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.action == 'create':
      return EventCreateSerializer
    elif self.action in ['update', 'partial_update']:
      return EventUpdateSerializer
    return super().get_serializer_class()
```